# Изменить атрибут "d" path'а кривой линии

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Я пытаюсь изменить "d" атрибут всех линий в определенной SVG карте, чтобы сделать прямые линии изогнутыми.

`d="M514 222L488 66"`

Есть ли универсальный алгоритм для изменения любой прямой линии c помощью атрибута "d" (как в примере  выше) и для получения в результате изогнутой линии?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Change path “d” attribute to curve the line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60744101/7394871) от участника  [@Free Lancer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13083933/free-lancer).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/60744101/7394871

Answer (score 6):

Ниже, как я хотел бы  сделать это: для кривой (quadratic Bézier curve Q) мне нужно вычислить положение контрольной точки.
В этом случае необходимо вычислить контрольную точку в середине линии на расстоянии R.

**Пожалуйста, прочтите комментарии в коде, чтобы понять как это сделано.**

```js
// переменная для определения кривизны 
let R = 50;
// точки исходной линии
let linePoints = [
  {x:514,y:222},
  {x:488,y:66}
]
//длина линии
let length = thePath.getTotalLength();
//точка в середине линии
let point = thePath.getPointAtLength(length/2);
// вычислить угол линии
let dy = linePoints[1].y - linePoints[0].y;
let dx = linePoints[1].x - linePoints[0].x;
let angle = Math.atan2(dy,dx);


let cp = {//контрольная точка для Безье перпендикулярной линии к траектории
  x:point.x + R*Math.cos(angle + Math.PI/2),
  y:point.y + R*Math.sin(angle + Math.PI/2)
}

//новый d атрибут для  path
let d = `M${linePoints[0].x}, ${linePoints[0].y} Q${cp.x},${cp.y} ${linePoints[1].x}, ${linePoints[1].y}`;
//установка нового "d" fnhb,enf
thePath.setAttributeNS(null,"d",d)
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 100vh;
}
path {
  stroke: black;
  fill: none;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox = "300 0 400 300">
<path id="thePath" d="M514, 222L488, 66" />
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [Change path “d” attribute to curve the line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60746352/7394871) от участника  [@enxaneta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7897395/enxaneta).</sub>

Comment: А я уж думал, оно интерактивное будет как обычно))

Comment: @Qwertiy так это затравка для дополнительных ответов. Есть желание подключайся. Или с помощью input менять положение точек и изменения при этом формы кривой, либо перетаскиванием точек, которые образуются при клике

Comment: @Qwertiy Привет!  ты хотел посмотреть, что-нибудь интерактивное по теме кривых Безье - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1103530/28748